# Unconventional .ZIP handling and find/replace in PHP

Tags: php, zip, base64

I have a slightly unconventional task I am trying to accomplish with .ZIP archives in PHP.  I have a zip archive used for an automation task (It's a startup package for Amazon EC2 instances) which contains a number of text and xml files.  What I need to do is find/replace a few pieces of text within those files, and output a BASE 64 encoded string (not write a new .zip file) using PHP on the fly.

I have no problem with getting the file contents and base64 enconding them with file_get_contents(), and base64_encode(), or the find/replace, it's the unzipping, and zipping to and from strings I can't seem to figure out.

I would like to avoid unzipping the archive, copying the files, editing the files writing a new .zip to disk, and then getting the contents and encoding that.  I was hoping there might be a solution that looks more like this:

1. Get the contents of the zip file into a string.

   ```
   $originalZipFile = file_get_contents('Path/To/ZipFile');
   ```
2. "Unzip" the data in that string, to a new string to expose the bits of text I want to find/replace.

   ```
   $unzippedFile = someFunction($originalZipFile);
   ```
3. Find and replace bits of text.

   ```
   $processedString = str_replace($find, $replace, $unzippedFile);
   ```
4. "Rezip" the processed string into a new string.

   ```
   $rezippedFile = someOtherFunction($processedString);
   ```
5. Base64 encode the "rezziped" string.

   ```
   $desiredOutputString = base64_encode($rezippedFile);
   ```

I have looked at the PHP ZipArchive class, but it doesn't seem to have the functions I'm looking for.

Any insights are greatly appreciated!

-Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I believe I found a pretty good solution to this.  For any others looking for similar solutions, I would recommend looking at the [ZipStream-PHP](http://pablotron.org/software/zipstream-php/) class by Paul Duncan.

With this class, you are able to dynamically write files, contents, and directories to a zip file, which is then streamed without writing a file to disk.

Pretty automagical.